# How to turn a button into a drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to click on the icon and drop down two options to pick from and change the placeholder in the input box to what the user selected.

```css
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

button,
input {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button,
input {
  *overflow: visible;
  line-height: normal;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media print {
  * {
    text-shadow: none!important;
    color: #000!important;
    background: transparent!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
  }
  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
  a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
    content: "";
  }
}

a {
  color: #188252;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #188252;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

form {
  margin: 0 0 18px;
}

input,
button {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
}

input,
button {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #555;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  width: 206px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
  -moz-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
  -o-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
  transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, .6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, .6);
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

input {
  margin-left: 0;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  color: #b94a48;
  border-color: #ee5f5b;
}

input:focus:invalid:focus {
  border-color: #e9322d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  input {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  input {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

[class^="icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: .25em;
  line-height: 14px;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before {
  font-family: 'IcoMoon';
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
}

.icon-arrow-down-3:before {
  content: "\e011";
}

.icon-search:before {
  content: "\53";
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-search form {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

a {
  color: #188252;
}

@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: ""!important;
  }
}

form#searchform {
  margin: 0;
}

.searchbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#searchterm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #188252;
  outline: 0px none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px 42px 4px 8px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

div.searchselect {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;
  right: 44px;
}

div.searchform {
  position: absolute;
  top: 99%;
  right: -2px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(220, 220, 220, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0.3rem .5rem -0.111rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

div.searchform a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: 0;
}

div.searchform a:hover,
div.searchform a:active,
div.searchform a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.expandsearchform {
  position: absolute;
  left: -24px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #188252;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.expandsearchform:hover,
.expandsearchform:focus {
  color: #666;
}

.expandsearchform i.icon-arrow-down-3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 16px;
}

.searchbar button.searchsubmit {
  width: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #188252;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.searchbar button.searchsubmit:hover,
.searchbar button.searchsubmit:focus {
  color: #def2e9;
}

a,
.searchbar button.searchsubmit {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/*! CSS Used fontfaces */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xFIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xMIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xEIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xLIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xHIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xGIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Italic'), local('Roboto-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xIIzIXKMny.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc3CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc-CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc2CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc5CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc1CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc0CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium Italic'), local('Roboto-MediumItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51S7ACc6CsTYl4BO.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic3CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic-CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic2CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic5CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic1CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic0CsTYl4BOQ3o.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold Italic'), local('Roboto-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOjCnqEu92Fr1Mu51TzBic6CsTYl4BO.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'IcoMoon';
  src: url('http://.info/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.eot');
  src: url('http://.info/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://gailborden.info/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.woff') format('woff'), url('http://gailborden.info/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://.info/media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.svg#IcoMoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <form id="searchform" name="searchform" action="" method="get" role="search">
    <div class="searchbar"><input name="searchType" value="smart" type="hidden" /> <input type="text" form="searchform" id="searchterm" name="query" value="" placeholder="Search the catalog" />
      <div class="searchselect">
        <div class="expandsearchform" class="dropdown-content"><i class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp;</i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="searchsubmit"><i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp;</i></button></div>
  </form>
</div>
<p>
  drop down should have two options, website and catalog. placeholder in input box should change accordingly.
</p>
```

Comment: I don't see any *dropdown* in the code provided. I really can't guess do you mean a default `select` is used or some styled `div`s or something.

Comment: @ths I have this so far https://jsfiddle.net/o4h152Lf/ but I want to change the placeholder also

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: I added an answer, it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the clicked element (when the dropdown is open) is one of the `a` tag elements (from the dropdown) then update the search `input`'s placeholder.

So `myFunction` becomes, don't forget to send the `event` in the `onclick` attribute in the `HTML` like so `onclick="myFunction(event)"` :

```
function myFunction(e) {
  console.log('click');
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  /** if that's an "a" tag that was clicked use its text as the placeholder **/
  e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'A' && document.getElementById('searchterm').setAttribute('placeholder', e.target.textContent);
}
```

Sorry for everyone I couldn't make a runnable snippet as the code (from the jsfiddle link) is messy but I made a [pen](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/WVdowP) to see the final result.